# Power BI: How to save slicer selected id in database against that login user

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-datasource

Power BI: How to save Slicer selected value in database against login user.i am using one table on sql server eg. as below
if user 1 select 5 option from slicer 1,2,3,4,5 and after click on save button that value should be save in database.

Userselectedfiltered Table

| userid | Slicerselectedid |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1,2,3,4,5 |
| 2 | 3,5,6 |